# sum array of Core Data entity attributes

Tags: core-data, swift3, xcode8, reduce, relationships

I have two core data entities, proposal and wageClass, and each has a to-many relationship to the other. WageClass has an `Int` attribute, numberOfWorkers. I need to sum the array of numberOfWorkers related to each proposal.

Currently I use this:

```
 let proposalNumberOfWorkers = proposal.value(forKeyPath: "wageClasses.numberOfWorkers")
```

and when I do this:

```
 let arraySum = proposalNumberOfWorkers.reduce(0, +)
```

I get an error that says type Any has no member reduce. When I eliminate the previous line of code and just try to print the array like this:

```
 totalWorkersLabel.text = "\(proposalNumberOfWorkers!)"
```

the `UILabel` looks like this: {(15)}

(15 being either the first or most recent item in the array, I'm not sure which)

So I'm wondering, 1) how do I make it .reduce, and 2) what the brackets and parens are about. Thanks in advance for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brackets and parentheses indicate that `proposalNumberOfWorkers!` is an `NSSet`.  `NSSet` does not recognise the `reduce` method.  `NSSet` and `Set` are bridged, so you can get what you need by casting `proposalNumberOfWorkers` as a `Set`:

```
let proposalNumberOfWorkers = proposal.value(forKeyPath: "wageClasses.numberOfWorkers") as! Set<Int>
```

and then use `reduce`.

Comment: Thanks! Works great!